# Did I ruin Toast command?

Tags: java, android, toast

[image]

Hello everyone I am a beginner with Android Studio.
It is redline under `makeText`
I think I ruined it.
It was working perfectly yesterday,
when I write `Toast.mak` there is no suggestion about `makeText` there is just `LENGHT_LONG LENGHT_SHORT Class` and `New` as you can see
What I need to do?

Comment: does it showing makeText function or not ?

Comment: It does not show it

Comment: Try `Invalidate Cache / Restart` from file option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to write down toast in lowercase and it will suggest you two option select second one the you don't need to write entire toast code all you have to pass the string.

Comment: i don't think he wrote in Small `t`. It's normal Way to call toast

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
there is red line under `(this, "message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)`
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild and clean your project. Sometime there are issues in the studio cache.